# On $s(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{\alpha}(t)dt$

Tags: integration, exponential-function, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

So, I am working on $$s(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{\alpha}(t)dt$$
Looking for a general form. Although I am not (really) asking you to evaluate the integral, I have some questions about my methods. Here's what I've done so far.

For all $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$,
$$I(t,\alpha)=\int\sin^{\alpha}(t)dt\\\therefore I(t,a)=(2i)^{-\alpha}\int\big(e^{it}-e^{-it}\big)^{\alpha}dt$$
Then, I note that for all $x\in(0,2)$, and any $\beta$, 
$$x^\beta=\,_1F_0(-\beta;;1-x)$$
My plan is to turn $\big(e^{it}-e^{-it}\big)^{\alpha}$ into $$_1F_0(-\alpha;;1-e^{it}+e^{-it})$$
expand the series, turn $1-e^{it}+e^{-it}$ into some trinomial expansion using the trinomial formula, then integrate term by term. But I am confused on whether or not this will work. But based on what I have previously stated, $_1F_0(-\alpha;;1-e^{it}+e^{-it})$ is only defined for $e^{-it}-e^{it}\in(0,2)$ which makes me worry that I won't be able carry out my plan, because $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\not\subset(0,2)$.

Ideally, you would reassure me that I am on the right path to a solution, but not everything goes my way. So, if I'm doing something wrong, or I can't get to a solution the way I want to, please inform me and show me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually be expressed in closed form in terms of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) as $$
\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sin^\alpha (t) dt = \frac12B\left(\frac{\alpha+1}2,\frac12\right)
$$
which can be rewritten in terms of the Gamma function as
$$
\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sin^\alpha (t) dt = \frac12B\left(\frac{\alpha+1}2,\frac12\right) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha+1}2)\Gamma(\frac12)}{2\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}2 + 1)} =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha+1}2)}{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}2 + 1)}  
$$
This can be seen by making the substitution $u = \sin^2(t)$, which gives
\begin{eqnarray}
t &=& \arcsin{\sqrt{u}}\\
dt &=& \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u(1-u)}}
\end{eqnarray}
Putting this into the original integral, obtain
$$
\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sin^\alpha (t) dt = \int_0^1\frac{u^{\frac{\alpha - 1}2}}{2\sqrt{1-u}} du = \frac12B\left(\frac{\alpha + 1}2,\frac12\right)
$$
as claimed above.

Comment: For what values of $\alpha$ does this work?

Comment: Anywhere the integral converges, so $\alpha > -1$.

Comment: Or if your working in $\mathbb{C}$, for $\Re{\alpha} > -1$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.